# Submit checkbox value on form without page refresh AJAX PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just started learning ajax and its really great and time saving i agree.

But i got stuck at this point sending form data without page reload.

**Below is my html code.**

```
<form id="form4" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="agreed" value="check">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="form-submit" name="submit" value="Send">
  <p class="form-message"></p>
</form>
```

**Below is my Ajax script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form4").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var action = 'another_test';
            var agreed = $("#agreed").val();
            var submit = $("#form-submit").val();
            $(".form-message").load("test3.php", {
                test: agreed,
                submit: submit,
                action: action
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Below is my php code**

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

        if ($_POST['action'] == 'another_test') {

            $test = $_POST["test"];
            $errorEmpty = false;


            if (!empty($test)) {
                echo "<p>Click the checkbox pls</p>";
                $errorEmpty = true;
            }

            else {
                echo "<p>Checkbox clicked</p>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error.. cant submit";
        }
    }

?>
<script>

    var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty ?>";
</script>
```

*The php file is on another page called test3.php*

This particular code works if it was an input text but doesn't work for a checkbox.
Please help me so i can learn well.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: .load() (as per the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/) performs a GET request, not a POST. To submit data, you'd be better to use $.post()

Comment: The php file its on another page

Comment: That's irrelevant to my point. Your PHP script is expecting a POST and you're sending it a GET. Whether that's a different script to the one that was loaded into the browser makes no difference to that fact. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ is what you need to use.

Comment: okay will check it out thanks

Comment: I gave you an example below, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load()` (as per the documentation) performs a GET request, not a POST, but your PHP is (as shown by the `$_POST` references) expecting a POST request - and it usually makes sense to submit form data using POST.

So you'd be better to use `$.post()` - this will send a POST request. Then you can handle the response and load it into your "form-message" element in the "done" callback triggered by that request.

N.B. You could also make the code shorter by putting the "action" variable as a hidden field in the form, and then simply serialize the form in one command instead of pulling each value out separately.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form4" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="agreed" value="check">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="form-submit" name="submit" value="Send">
  <input type="hidden" action="another_test"/>
  <p class="form-message"></p>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form4").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.post(
          "test3.php", 
          $(this).serialize()
        ).done(function(data) { 
            $(".form-message").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Documentation:

[jQuery Load](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

[jQuery Post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

[jQuery Serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Thanks. Have Learnt something great from you.

Comment: No problem. if the answer has helped please remember to mark it as "accepted" and / or leave an upvote - thanks :-)